# Spring xml problem part 2

Tags: xml, spring

I just asked a question: [Spring xml problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6943031/spring-xml-problem)
I solved the problem, but now i got another one:

> Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop]

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

<bean id="audience" class="springaop.Audience">
</bean>

<bean id="sam" class="springaop.Singer">
    <property name="id" value="1"></property>
</bean>

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="audience">

        <aop:before pointcut="* springaop.Singer.perform(..)" 
        method="takeSeats"></aop:before>

    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>

</beans>
```

I use Spring 3.1.0.M2

Comment: Try using 3.0.5.RELEASE.  The 3.1 milestone builds are unstable and buggy.

Comment: With 3.0.5 I get: "Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [aop-conf.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aopalliance/aop/Advice"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd get that error if you don't have the spring-aop artifact on your classpath. You'd also get it if you somehow included the spring-aop classes without having available the META-INF/spring.handlers entry from that jar. That file is how Spring finds its "namespace handlers". The on in the spring-aop jar is what tells spring how to handle the "http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" namespace. One way you can get this problem is by trying to create a fat jar including several spring jars. You'll end up overwriting all the spring.handlers files with one of the others and losing a lot of essential entries.